# How can I add line break for large matrices? My matrix is too large and the right side can be submerged

Tags: matrices, arrays

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \frac{\epsilon  m_w^2 x_t}{6 \epsilon ^2-7 \epsilon +2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{\epsilon  m_w^2 \left(x_t-1\right){}^2}{\left(6 \epsilon ^2-7 \epsilon
   +2\right) \left(x_t+1\right)} & \frac{2 (\epsilon -1)}{(3 \epsilon -2)
   \left(x_t+1\right)} & \frac{2 (\epsilon -1) x_t}{(3 \epsilon -2)
   \left(x_t+1\right)} & -\frac{2 (\epsilon -1) m_w^2 x_t}{(3 \epsilon -2)
   \left(x_t+1\right)} \\
 0 & -\frac{\epsilon  \left(\epsilon ^3+\epsilon ^2+\epsilon -2\right)
   \left(x_t-1\right)}{\left(6 \epsilon ^5-\epsilon ^4+\epsilon ^3+\epsilon ^2-5
   \epsilon +2\right) \left(x_t+1\right)} & \frac{-2 \epsilon ^4 x_t+3 \epsilon 
   \left(x_t-1\right)-2 x_t+2}{\left(3 \epsilon ^4+\epsilon ^3+\epsilon
   ^2+\epsilon -2\right) m_w^2 \left(x_t-1\right) x_t \left(x_t+1\right)} &
   \frac{-2 \epsilon ^4 x_t+3 \epsilon  \left(x_t-1\right)-2 x_t+2}{\left(3
   \epsilon ^4+\epsilon ^3+\epsilon ^2+\epsilon -2\right) m_w^2 \left(x_t-1\right)
   \left(x_t+1\right)} & \frac{2 \epsilon ^4 x_t-3 \epsilon  x_t+2 x_t+3 \epsilon
   -2}{\left(3 \epsilon ^4+\epsilon ^3+\epsilon ^2+\epsilon -2\right)
   \left(x_t-1\right) \left(x_t+1\right)} \\
\end{array}
\right)\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use  the `\splitfrac`command, from `mathtools`, to have  multilined numerators or denominators, when these are very long.

Comment: Unrelated advise use pmatrix for the matrix and remove all `\left... \right` pairs, here they do nothing and just makes the code harder to read.

Comment: In my opinion your readers are better of if you say "to ease notation, define “, then define say a letter for each fraction and use those in the matrix. Absolutely noone want to read a matrix with entries this complicated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following up on @daleif's comment and suggestions: If you want to give yourself a halfway decent chance that your readers will actually bother to look closely at the 9 fractional expressions, you better display them separately, say along the ideas of the answer shown below.

Note that one may express `a_{44}` and `a_{45}` in terms of `a_{43}`; similarly, `a_{54}` and `a_{55}` may be expressed as functions of `a_{53}`. (Your readers will probably appreciate being informed about that.)

I would definitely remove all 21 [!] pairs of `\left` and `\right` sizing directives, especially as they don't do anything useful; they do mess up the spacing, though. In the code below, I also encase the `align*` env. in a `spreadlines` environment to increase the linespacing between the rows of the `align*` env. by 6pt over the default.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'spreadlines' env; load 'amsmath' automatically
\allowdisplaybreaks % allow page breaks in long display-math env.s
\begin{document}
\[
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 0      & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0      & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 a_{31} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} & a_{45} \\
 0 & a_{52} & a_{53} & a_{54} & a_{55} 
\end{pmatrix}
\]
where 
%% Increase spacing between lines 
%% (increase value of "\jot" from 3pt to 6pt)
\begin{spreadlines}{6pt} 
\begin{align*}
a_{31} &= \frac{\epsilon m_w^2 x_t}{6\epsilon^2-7\epsilon +2} \\
a_{42} &= \frac{\epsilon m_w^2 (x_t-1){}^2}{(6\epsilon^2-7\epsilon +2) (x_t+1)} \\
a_{43} &= \frac{2 (\epsilon -1)}{(3\epsilon -2)(x_t+1)} \\
a_{44} %&= \frac{2 (\epsilon -1) x_t}{(3\epsilon -2) (x_t+1)}  \\*
       &=  a_{43}x_t\\
a_{45} %&= -\frac{2 (\epsilon -1) m_w^2 x_t}{(3\epsilon -2)(x_t+1)} \\*
       &= -m_w^2 a_{44}\\
a_{52} &= -\frac{\epsilon (\epsilon^3+\epsilon^2+\epsilon -2) (x_t-1)}{(6\epsilon^5-\epsilon^4+\epsilon^3+\epsilon^2-5\epsilon +2) (x_t+1)} \\
a_{53} &= \frac{-2\epsilon^4 x_t+3\epsilon (x_t-1)-2 x_t+2}{(3\epsilon^4+\epsilon^3+\epsilon^2+\epsilon -2) m_w^2 (x_t-1) x_t (x_t+1)} \\
a_{54} %&= \frac{-2\epsilon^4 x_t+3\epsilon (x_t-1)-2 x_t+2}{(3\epsilon^4+\epsilon^3+\epsilon^2+\epsilon -2) m_w^2 (x_t-1)(x_t+1)} \\*
       &= a_{53}x_t \\
a_{55} %&= \frac{-(2\epsilon^4 x_t+3\epsilon (x_t-1)-2 x_t+2)}{(3\epsilon^4+\epsilon^3+\epsilon^2+\epsilon -2)(x_t-1) (x_t+1)} \\*
       &= -m_w^2 a_{54}
\end{align*} 
\end{spreadlines}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tip: if I remember correctly mathtools(or amsmath) has a spreadlines env to locally set jot around a math display

Comment: @daleif - Many thanks for the suggestion to employ a `spreadlines` environment. I've updated my answer accordingly.